# Exception changing password of existing SQL Server CE database

Tags: sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

Using SQL Server CE 4.0.8876.1 (NuGet package). I'm trying to change the password of an existing SQL Server CE database as per this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/compact/sql-ce-3.0/reference/kt1a3805(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Perhaps I cannot change the password if the existing database is already encrypted?

```
var oldConnStr = "DataSource=\"C:\\temp\\FilePath.sdf\";Persist Security Info=False; 
password=oldPass; Encrypt Database=True; flush interval=1";
var updatePasswordConnStr = "DataSource=; password=newPass; Encrypt Database=True;";

using (var sqlCeEngine = new SqlCeEngine(oldConnStr))
{
    sqlCeEngine.Compact(null);
    sqlCeEngine.Compact(updatePasswordConnStr);
}
```

I keep getting the following exception when I call `sqlCeEngine.Compact` (both calls):

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException
> HResult=0x80004005
> Message=The password specified for the source database is incorrect. [ Data Source = FilePath.sdf ]
> Source=SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
>
> StackTrace:
> at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeEngine.Repair(SEFIXOPTION option, String dstConnStr, RepairOption repairOption)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm OK it is working now.

```
var updatePasswordConnStr = "DataSource=; password=newPass;";
```